# What is the most efficient way to calculate time between dates in R?

Tags: r

I have a large data set (as a csv) and wish to calculate the time between dates. What is the most efficient way to do this?
eg, data:

```
ID    start        end
01    01-04-2017   05-04-2017
01    04-04-2017   06-04-2017
01    11-04-2017   21-04-2017
02    19-05-2017   22-05-2017
02    22-05-2017   24-05-2017
02    02-06-2017   05-06-2017
02    09-06-2017   12-06-2017
...
```

It's not so simple because there may be overlaps - as shown above.

What I'd like as output is:

```
ID    time
01    15
02    11
...
```

I've thought about splitting the data into a list based on the ID (`split(dataframe(df$start, df$end), df$ID)`) but this is slow for a large dataframe. I've also considered looping through the df and comparing the differences but this is also slow.
Is there an efficient way to do this in R?

Comment: what language is this? is a database? sql? java? maybe tagging your question could help. In this way is too broad.

Comment: @OscarAkaElvis It's tagged as R and ends with "Is there an efficient way to do this in R?"

Comment: Thanks @OscarAkaElvis, I've amended the question appropriately - the data are in csv format and I want to use R (if possible).

Comment: Ok understood. Sorry can't help here, don't know R.

Comment: It is easy to calculate the difference between the time difference start and end once you convert these two columns to Date class. Could you clarify your desired output more?

Comment: thanks @ycw. I like the 'difftime' function as I may want to extend this into hours also and it is easy to calculate the times. However, dealing with the overlaps is the issue. Ideally I'd collapse those where there is overlap but I don't know how to do that efficiently for a large data set in R.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. How do you obtained time=15 for ID= 1?

Comment: @ed_sans, it's because there are overlapping dates so you can't just add the differences.

Comment: @EddieS please, look at my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` to check which interval of start dates each value of `end` falls into. If they overlap, two will have the same interval, which can be used for grouping and aggregation to eliminate overlaps:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table(text = 'ID    start        end
01    01-04-2017   05-04-2017
01    04-04-2017   06-04-2017
01    11-04-2017   21-04-2017
02    19-05-2017   22-05-2017
02    22-05-2017   24-05-2017
02    02-06-2017   05-06-2017
02    09-06-2017   12-06-2017', header = TRUE, colClasses = 'character') %>% 
    mutate_at(-1, as.Date, format = '%d-%m-%Y')    # parse dates

df_aggregated <- df %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    group_by(ID, overlap = findInterval(end, start)) %>% 
    summarise(start = min(start), end = max(end)) %>% 
    select(-overlap) %>% ungroup()    # clean up

df_aggregated
#> # A tibble: 5 × 3
#>      ID      start        end
#>   <chr>     <date>     <date>
#> 1    01 2017-04-01 2017-04-06
#> 2    01 2017-04-11 2017-04-21
#> 3    02 2017-05-19 2017-05-24
#> 4    02 2017-06-02 2017-06-05
#> 5    02 2017-06-09 2017-06-12
```

Once the data is tidied, summarizing is easy:

```r
df_aggregated %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(span = sum(end - start))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>      ID    span
#>   <chr>  <time>
#> 1    01 15 days
#> 2    02 11 days
```

This approach assumes each group is ordered by `start`; if not, add `arrange(start)`.

Comment: This looks good but I get an error with "mutate_at": 'could not find function "mutate_at"'.

Comment: Assuming it's not just because dplyr isn't loaded, `mutate_at` been in dplyr since version 0.5. Updating from CRAN or GitHub should dispel the error.

Comment: I have the package and loaded it with "library()".

Comment: What does `packageVersion('dplyr')` return?